# Why is my PHP Built in development server no longer responsive?

Tags: php, windows, server, ip, windows-server-2016

Good Evening Everyone,

I've been learning PHP and I'm using the built in server to learn the syntax and running simple scripts and web pages. I've been going at it for a better part of 3 weeks now but suddenly this evening. When I try to load my php webpage(s) it would load one page (or hang) then when I'd go to another page I wrote it would either hang or not load at all (Chrome is continuously *"waiting on host"*). I've been running Windows Server 2016 64 bit (very clean box here). I haven't had any problems with playing with the built in server until today. We are talking about very SIMPLE hello, world scrips with a couple of html tags here or there. I'm using version 7.2.0 64 bit Development Server. I ever tried x86 for giggles and it demonstrates the same behavior.

my command: `php -S localhost:8000` (or any open port) I even used my IP to no avail. Suddenly my development sever just stopped working. I've made no changes to my PC.

I'm not receiving any errors or anything when I try to load my pages. What gives? I've made no changes to the `ini` file. I can attach if needed. Thank You guys so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out there was a command I was running within one of my php scripts that was causing it to hang! It's working now.